# Twitter no longer posts to Facebook page

Tags: facebook, twitter

I have 2 Twitter accounts and 2 Facebook pages.

Everything was working fine all my tweets was posted to each Facebook page automatically until around 11 April 2013. Is there anything Facebook changed?

I've done these:

1. Remove Facebook page from Twitter
2. Remove Twitter app from Facebook page.
3. Remove Facebook app.
4. Create a new app.
5. Added the Facebook app to the very same Facebook page (example. Mysite.com app added to mysite.com Facebook page)

Really don't know what else I should do. Like I said everything worked just fine until around 11 April.

Am I missing something here?  Also. I followed the guides provided by Facebook. No luck with that. I contacted Twitter too and the first answer was to check Facebook. Now I replied. Waiting again for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since everything is failing I'd recommend you to use Selective Tweets. [Use this guide](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20071729-285/how-to-post-only-certain-tweets-to-facebook/)

> If you are active on both Twitter and Facebook then you probably
>   already know how much work it can be to keep both feeds updated. Some
>   people prefer to keep their Facebook private, while Twitter lends
>   itself to more impersonal interaction and updates. Although there are
>   services that send every tweet to Facebook, that isn't always the
>   ideal solution for users.
>
> Selective Twitter allows you to pick which tweets will be posted on
>   your Facebook account. In this simple guide we will show you how to
>   set up the service, and how to use it
>   You may be greeted with a prompt similar to the one above to turn off
>   secure browsing. It's all right to click on Continue, just make sure
>   to log out and back in to Facebook after you are done setting up
>   Selective Twitter to force your Facebook account back into an https
>   connection.
>   After you have logged in and pressed Continue to go past the
>   secure-connection warning, you should see a screen similar to the one
>   above. All you have to do to set up the Selective Twitter service is
>   input your Twitter username, and press Save.
>
> One thing to keep in mind is that if your Twitter account is set to
>   private, Selective Twitter will not work. The service relies on
>   Twitters' public search, a search that doesn't return private account
>   tweets.

Comment: Hi .. Thanks for your reply ..that will not work because my tweets are coming from a different source ... I dont write the tweets myself .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twitter and Facebook integration is [discontinued and no longer available](https://www.kenyans.co.ke/news/32236-facebook-locks-out-cross-posting-twitter).

The only way to connect Twitter and Facebook is with https://2FB.me

A Chrome extension that makes tweets made by other people shareable by letting you react to them on Twitter.

Another way is by copying the tweet status url after the 2FB.me link: https://2FB.me/https://twitter.com/ShowHNDaily/status/1032829865853104128